# spark register expression for SQL DSL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, catalyst-optimizer

How can I access a catalyst expression (not regular UDF) in spark SQL scala DSL API?

http://geospark.datasyslab.org only allows for text based execution

```
GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(sparkSession)
var stringDf = sparkSession.sql(
  """
    |SELECT ST_SaveAsWKT(countyshape)
    |FROM polygondf
  """.stripMargin)
```

When I try to use the SQL scala DSL
`df.withColumn("foo", ST_Point(col("x"), col("y")))` I get an error of type mismatch expected column got **ST_Point**.

What do I need to change to properly register the `catalyst expression` as something which is callable directly via scala SQL DSL API?

### edit

catalyst expressions are all registered via https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/fadccf2579e4bbe905b2c28d5d1162fdd72aa99c/sql/src/main/scala/org/datasyslab/geosparksql/UDF/UdfRegistrator.scala#L38:

```
Catalog.expressions.foreach(f=>sparkSession.sessionState.functionRegistry.createOrReplaceTempFunction(f.getClass.getSimpleName.dropRight(1),f))
```

### edit2

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_Point
val  myPoint = udf((x: Double, y:Double) => ST_Point _)
```

fails with:

```
_ must follow method; cannot follow org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_Point.type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access expressions that aren't exposed in the org.apache.spark.sql.functions package using the `expr` method. It doesn't actually give you a UDF-like object in Scala, but it does allow you to write the rest of your query using the Dataset API.

Here's an example from [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@expr(expr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
// get the number of words of each length
df.groupBy(expr("length(word)")).count()
```

Comment: That is a great workaround, but I still would like to learn how to perform the registration so it is properly available as a typesafe scala DSL function

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that you can use to call the UDF and what I've done so far.

```
      .withColumn("locationPoint", callUDF("ST_Point", col("longitude"),
        col("latitude")))
```